# Make div with opacity:0 have no physical dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a function where you hover over a div, which will result in another div appearing; a simple, CSS-only pop-over.

However, whenever the pop-over-div has an `opacity:0`, it still has a physical height and width, rendering other divs under the pop-over unreachable.

I know I can work with `display:none` and `display:block`, but this will remove the possibility of adding a smooth "arrival" of the div; it'll just pop in and out of the screen.

**The question**: Is there a way to remove the physical dimensions of a div with `opacity:0`?

In my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avt1oLtz/15/), you will notice you can get the `.iconhover` to appear when you hover over the `H` or `e`. If you hover over the rest of the word, you're officially hovering over `.iconhover` and not `.wishicon`, resulting in the pop-over not showing up.

I hope my question is clear enough.

**HTML**

```
<div class="qs">
    <div class="wishicon">Hello world</div>
    <div class="iconhover">Hovering...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.iconhover {
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left:-0px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
    padding:4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
}

.qs > .wishicon:hover + .iconhover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a terrific solution which I use often.
On the element with opacity: 0 put pointer-events: none.
It will still have the dimensions, but it will be as if all events are inactive.
Then when you want it to be opacity: 1, return pointer-events to auto.
This is the next best thing to using display: block/none but it can be transitioned!

Comment: Although that does fix the problem, it's not a very "pretty" result, check the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avt1oLtz/16/ Great solution though, I will mark it as accepted, although the result is not 100% what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

That would certainly be nice, but alas, I'm not aware of any "ghost" CSS property.

I would treat it the same as a hover menu: make the *parent* hoverable instead of the previous sibling:

```
.qs:hover > .iconhover { opacity: 1; ... }
```

Comment: Sadly, this means the `.iconhover` is also a trigger to show himself, as he is placed in that same parent. For now I solved it with just `display:`, but that doesn't support any nice transition effects.

Comment: Yeah, that was my observation too. I was serious when I said "that would be nice"... I have more than once wanted to do the same thing but not let the higher `z-index` element block my hovers on lower elements.

Comment: What is your application for it? Maybe some creative thinking will come up with another solution.

Comment: It's to give some icons a pop-over, to explain what they do. There are probably some good solutions with jQuery or something, but I wanted to try it with pure CSS.

Comment: Oh, I would certainly use CSS as much as possible. I **never** want pop-overs to hide what they're actually describing... I personally would just position it *off of* the element you're hovering.

Comment: Well, of course the final product wouldn't be `Hello World` but just an icon. The problem is though, that we would have multiple icons in a row and any icon that's below the pop-over of the first icon, is not hoverable.
I tried moving the pop-over outside of the table, but forgot that then whatever is outside of that table is not hoverable or clickable. `display:` ends up being the best solution, what a shame of those beautiful transitions!